# How to display clear images

Tags: codenameone

when displaying images in codename 1 form they appear blurred, where is and how can I solve the problem?

Have tried displaying them using image viewer and ImageLabel but non seems to work for me

```
    Image image = URLImage.createToStorage(
            EncodedImage.createFromImage(Utils.getTheme().getImage("default_avatar.png"), false), imageName,
            imageUrl);
    ImageViewer imageViewer = new ImageViewer(image);
    imageViewer.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
```

Comment: About image quality, usually there is a difference between the Codename One Simulator and real devices. In the Simulator, there could be a change of image quality enabling and disabling the "scrollable" option (in the Simulator menù). Also the "zoom" option can affect image quality. Said that, as Shai answered, the use of `ImageViewer` to zoom an image and of `URLImage` that scales an image to the same size of `default_avatar.png` results in a poor image quality. `URLImage` is fine to show an image in a `Label`.

Answer (score 1):

When you download an image with `URLImage` it's scaled to to the size of `default_avatar.png`. That would mean you lost all the pixels of a larger size. You should use something like:

```
ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest();
cr.downloadImageToStorage(imageName, img -> {
    // callback when image downloaded
});
```

Comment: Please give more details how I can display the images after downloading them using this

Comment: Just add them to the UI in the callback e.g. `imageViewer.setImage(img);`